# BCM4312 drops after a while

Tags: 11.10, broadcom

I'm running 11.10 with BCM4312 wireless. I can connect to a network just fine, and I can have an internet connection for a while...but then it drops, but it still says that it is connected on the icon. I can't access any pages.

Any ideas? I'm at my university and I can't mess with the router...this is a big problem for me, since I have to listen to a lot of streaming music for my major. Help!!!!!

-Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a different driver. To figure out which one is currently in use, run the 
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` command. For example, if the output shows that `wl` module is loaded, try removing `bcmwl-kernel-source` and installing `b43`. B43 is just another driver for broadcom cards.

Edit:

Open the Software Center, search for `bcmwl-kernel-source` and remove it, then search for `firmware-b43-lpphy-installer` and install it. Reboot when done.

You may need to load the `b43` module manually if there no wireless after that.

`sudo modprobe b43`

Comment: Here is my output:


09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
 Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:02cf]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
 Kernel driver in use: wl

i'm still a little noobish to linux....what exactly do I do from here?

Comment: See the edit above.

Comment: This works so far perfectly! :) Thank you!!!! If anything comes up, I'll come back and post so others can know.

Comment: It....has stopped working. :( It does just the same thing. Sooooo.. I'm going to ask the tech support here at my school if I have the correct credentials entered. Which I probably don't.

I do appreciate your help Mike :) unfortunately, my laptop just doesn't want to work now :(