# Ubuntu 20.04LTS - not recognizing Wifi intermittently

Tags: wireless

The issue I am facing is quite strange. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Dell inspiron laptop. The issue is sometimes my Wifi network wont even show up in the list . The network list will show other nearby Wifi(s) but not mine. I tried to restart multiple times but no use. If i dont use a laptop for a day, then next day it would recognize my Wifi and will work fine for few days . I checked other question but could not find any solution. I even re-installed Ubuntu . My machine currently uses Broadcom driver BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY

Comment: Hi, I seem to be having the same problem. I don't know how to go about it though https://askubuntu.com/questions/1357883/i-can-t-see-my-wireless-network-in-the-list

Comment: Looks like an integrated card with bluetooth and I have had issues on the last few laptops. Can you add the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` please?

Comment: hi @darth_epoxy , here is the output

Comment: 0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1397 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:000c]
 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR+ FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
 Region 0: Memory at f69fc000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Kernel driver in use: wl
 Kernel modules: ssb, wl

Comment: Dude that's an old one, I thought you may have made a typo, sorry for assuming. Try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/104972/bcm4312-drops-after-a-while